# What files to modify when adding code to theme_scripts.js so that the changes are displayed backpack laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have implemented my own theme and according to the documentation:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/add-ons-tutorial-how-to-create-a-theme#theme-scripts

There is a file:
my-cool-theme/inc/theme_scripts.blade.php

Where you can place code that works for the theme.

The problem is that every time I add code, it shows up immediately in local, but when I update the file in production nothing happens.

I have tried deleting all types of cache with artisan, deleting certain files and nothing. I don't know if I necessarily have to do a deploy.

Does anyone know what the short or correct way is? It is not so easy for me due to access issues and the shared server. But I don't see much use in a file that requires doing much more to display javascript or CSS code.
I have another very specific problem that forced me to put the code there and it has been quite a problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so Backpack uses [Laravel-Backpack/basset](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/basset), the problem is that your file is being updated, but since there is no reference of any update, the server is using the first version that was cached.

To avoid this you can either;

---

1. Clear the cache on each deploy, most probably with an automated script (recommended).

You have the [following commands on docs](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/basset#the-basset-commands);

```
php artisan basset:clear         # clears the basset directory
php artisan basset:cache         # internalizes all @bassets
```

If you run these on a deploy, you'll make sure basset will clear all assets, and recache them again.

---

2. You can also version your files.

If you update a CDN asset, basset works seamlessly because the version of the asset changes, for instance; `https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.js`.
The version is "hardcoded" in the path.

You can do this for your scripts `@basset(base_path('vendor/package/your-theme/resources/assets/js/your-theme-1.0.1.js'))`.

Once you change the version, Basset will cache the new version for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your complete response.

I used those commands before writing here, but it gave me the following error:
The command "basset:clear" does not exist.

That's why I tried to try somewhere else by deploying again and uploading everything as if it were a first implementation (I'm still in development) and even then the `<script></script>` instructions were not recognized.

I feel like there are some weird things, I've just seen some people have had related issues.
As soon as I have the opportunity, I will look for a solution to the error it gives me and do other tests.